# what's wrong with my int?

Tags: c, size, int

I've tried using the following command:

```
 __m128i b = _mm_set_epi32 (y, y, x, x);
```

Where y and x are ints.

Where I run the debugger I see that b is of type: **unsigned __int64[2]**

I intended b to be 4 integers of 32 bits each (I think that's what they say here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/019beekt.aspx )

Do you know what's wring with my code?

Thanks

Comment: what lang? tag correctly please

Comment: What language are you using? Please use a tag and say in your question

Comment: `_mm_set_epi32` is irrelevant. The type of `b` is whatever `__m128i` is typedef'd to. Whatever `_mm_set_epi32` does cannot change the type of `b`, so if the type of `b` is not what you expect it to be, don't look at `_mm_set_epi32`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a problem here - a 128-bit integer is represented by two 64-bit integers, which is the largest native type outside of SSE registers a 64-bit Intel CPU can handle.

Your debugger is likely showing the "real" type, not the typedefed or macro'd type.

Comment: If `__m128i` were a typedef-name for an array type, the above code wouldn't compile, since arrays are not assignable/copy-initializable. `__m128i` is probably not a typedef-name, but rather some intrinsic implementation-specific type that stands for a quadruple of 32-bit integers, and which just happens to show in the debugger as `unsigned __int64[2]`. It is just a debugger's bug-feature, which has little relation to the true nature of `__m128i`.

Answer (score 0):

Typedefs are aliases, odds are good your debugger is showing you the value __m128i is aliased to.  In C the only real way to define a new type is through the struct keyword; all other techniques (typedef, etc) lead to type aliases which can be replaced with their equivalents.

Assuming that is true, is there an issue other than it is displaying differently than you expected?